# Overriding Magento Save method

Tags: product, overrides, save

We have a attribute 'short-description' in our product listing page. We want to escape html characters e.g. "&" => "&amp;" , and append information to it when our admin hit 'save' in product editing page. Which file / method should I be looking into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't override the `save` method.
Use an observer.
You can observe the event `catalog_product_save_before`.
Your method could look like this:

```
public function catalogProductSaveBefore($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $shortDescription = $product->getShortDescription();
    $shortDescription = ...process your short description here
    $product->setShortDescription($shortDescription); 
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addNotice('your message for admin here');
}
```

Read more about how [event observers work in here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).

Comment: Works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

You can start to debug from `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController::saveAction()`. This method holds product saving action. So you need to rewrite this controller file

File : `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controller/Catalog/ProductController.php`

```
public function saveAction()
{
     $short_descr = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shor_description');
     if ($short_descr != '') {
         //do something with it
     }
}
```

Hope it helps